# Can someone identify this bean vine?

Tags: identification, vines

We have a been vine in the backyard, and are wondering if it's good to eat.

The ruler is in cm, not inches.
[image: bean pod and leaves]

[image: top of vine]
[image: middle of vine]
[image: bottom of vine]

Comment: Can you get a picture of the full vine?

Comment: @ashes999: I added some pictures of the vine (I'm assuming closeup is better than seeing literally the full vine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant looks like wisteria to me. Hard to tell since the plant has mostly lost its leaves in the picture and doesn't have flowers. You may want to look at wisteria pictures online and compare them to what your plant looks like in the summer.

Unfortunately, wisteria beans are poisonous, so don't eat.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisteria_sinensis

Comment: I'll have to wait for summer to tell for sure, but I'm accepting this answer as it's probably correct.